# React Native run on multiple simultaneous Android emulators

Tags: javascript, android, android-emulator, react-native

I would like to test my app on at least 2 Android emulators simultaneously. I can start 2 emulators but can't seem to find how to `react-native run-android` my app on 2 emulators with ADB. If possible I would also like to be able to run a `react-native log-android` on each one while testing my app.

Is there a way to do so ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can only do it on different ports. Because one port, one listener :/
**Solve:**

```
react-native start --port 9988
./emulator -port 9988 -avd devicename1

react-native start --port 9999
./emulator -port 9999 -avd devicename2
```

### Edit2:

Before running the emulator, You can write in the terminal and then run it:

```
function emulator { cd "$(dirname "$(which emulator)")" && ./emulator "$@"; }
```

First emulator is **react** .

```
emulator -port 9988 @react
react-native run-android ( automaticaly detect emulator )
```

Second emulator is **r** .

```
emulator -port 8081 @r
react-native run-android (automaticaly detect emulator )
```

[image]

Comment: That's a nice idea, but I can't seem to open 2 emulators at one even with specifying the ports

Comment: @AntoineAuffray update my solve :) you can try it :)

Comment: Excellent ! Now the problem is that the `react-native run-android` command always run on the first emulator launched, any idea ? We're getting close !

Comment: @AntoineAuffray you can try react-native start --port=9988 in project folder

Comment: Ah yes I see what you're doing there, that's great. Thanks for all this, answer accepted !

Comment: @AntoineAuffray 
Is the problem solved ? :) it is ok ı hope problem is solved :)

Comment: In my case it works only without specifying the `--port` in `react-native start` command (2 devices listen on one instance of this command).

Comment: where i write this function emulator { cd "$(dirname "$(which emulator)")" && ./emulator "$@"; }

Answer (score 13):

In order to run your react application on multiple emulators, just start 2 emulators as usual and then use the command `react-native run-android`.

You can even specify any port number as `react-native run-android --port 8084` if you want. Your app will start on both the emulators simultaneously. :)

[Have a look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtfIu.png)

Comment: Confirmed this worked for me... did not need to overcomplicate it. Thank you!

Comment: works.  wish i knew how to "attach" another emulator without starting everything over

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer by @Burhan Yılmaz did NOT work for me. This is probably due to new updates and development in the relevant software. The following steps demonstrate what worked for me.

1. Start the 1st emulator, e.g. 
   `emulator -avd Nexus_S_API_28`
2. Start the 2nd emulator, e.g. 
   `emulator -avd Nexus_S_API_28_2`
3. Start React-Native in the same way, which you would usually use (without specifying any ports.) 
   `react-native run-android`

This sends a copy of the code to both devices. However, each device runs its copy in isolation from the other device.

Environment Details:

- MS Windows 10
- Android SDK 29.0.2
- React-Native: 0.61.2

Comment: It was as easy like this still! I think this should be the accected answer at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

First you check available android devices by running the following command.

```
adb devices
```

[image]

After that you can use the following command to start react native project with specific port and device id.

```
npm run android -port PORT_NO -deviceId=DEVICE_ID
```

In the example above we can run the command in two separate terminals.

```
npm run android -port 9988 -deviceId=067682514L113728 
npm run android -port 9989 -deviceId=emulator-5554
```

Answer (score -1):

Using [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/), you just have to start 2 instances and start them as if there was only one (`react-native run-android` to install the app and `react-native start`)