# How to run react-native expo app on multiple emulators?

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator, expo

Does anyone know how to run an expo react-native app on multiple android emulators at once?
I have tried to run the app after running the emulators but it would run only on one emulator.
When I tried 'shift+a' it shows a list of emulators but when I choose the desired emulator it doesn't work.
This is the error 'Couldn't start a project on Android: The emulator (Nexus_S_API_30) quit before it finished opening. You can try starting the emulator manually from the terminal with: emulator @Nexus_S_API_30'
This says the emulator exited even though it is already running.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native run on multiple simultaneous Android emulators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45588482/react-native-run-on-multiple-simultaneous-android-emulators)

Comment: No. I want to do that on expo. I think that's for apps built with react native cli.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install app in all emulator
2. Open all emulator
3. Run project from different port

   For example

   ```
   Run 'npx react-native start' for first emulator

   Run 'npx react-native start --port 9988' from another terminal for second emulator etc
   ```
4. Open app from emulators
5. Open developer menu by pressing **ctrl + m**
6. Change bundle location to '10.0.2.2:`PortNumber`' eg : '10.0.2.2:9988'

Comment: Will this work for expo?